# Using &rest parameters in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am having some trouble using *&rest parameters* in a lisp program (with Common Lisp).

My knowledge of the syntax not being perfect, I may be doing something wrong.

I have two functions:

```
(defun func-one(&rest params) .....)

(defun func-two(param-a param-b &rest params) .....)
```

They are working but at some point, inside func-one I need to make a call to function-two, like this:

```
(func-two value-a value-b params)
```

I presume what I want is clear to a human reader, but my syntax is wrong because I get an error message like:

```
*** _ =: (1 2 3 4 5) is not a number
```

Since "&rest params" is meant to hold a list of numbers, I understand the message.
But how can I get the result I want?

```
(1 2 3 4 5) passed in the "&rest params" should be seen as : 1 2 3 4 5 by func-two
and not as one element which is a list (indeed not a number).
```

So, what is the right way to call func-two? Instead of what I did.

Comment: A simple way is to call `(apply #'func-two value-a value-b params)`.

Comment: Be aware that argument lists have an implementation specific length limit. It can be as low as 50 (example: ABCL for the JVM). See the value of the variable `call-arguments-limit`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this answer I'll start by explaining what the problem is, and then show two different approaches to solving it.

### Understanding the problem

Start by looking at the two definitions:

```
(defun func-one (&rest params) ...)
```

So, `func-one` is a function that takes any number of arguments (including zero).  Inside its body all the arguments will be wrapped in a list and will be bound to `params`: the length of `params` will be the number of arguments provided to the function.

```
(defun func-two (param-a param-b &rest params) ...)
```

`func-two` takes *at least two* arguments, and as many as you like (up to the implementation limit: this is true for `func-one` as well).  The first two arguments will be bound to `param-a` and `param-b`, and *all the rest of the arguments* will be wrapped in a list and bound to `params`.

So we can write a little fake version of `func-two` which explains what arguments it gets:

```
(defun func-two (param-1 param-2 &rest params)
  (format t "~&~D arguments~%param-1: ~S~%param-2: ~S~%params:  ~S~%"
          (+ 2 (length params))
          param-1 param-2 params)
  (values))
```

And now we can call it in various ways:

```
> (func-two 1 2)
2 arguments
param-1: 1
param-2: 2
params:  nil

> (func-two 1 2 3)
3 arguments
param-1: 1
param-2: 2
params:  (3)

> (func-two 1 2 3 4)
4 arguments
param-1: 1
param-2: 2
params:  (3 4)

> (func-two 1 2 '(3 4))
3 arguments
param-1: 1
param-2: 2
params:  ((3 4))
```

And here's the problem: if you already *have* a bunch of things packed up into a list, then when you call `func-two`, that list is only *one* argument to the function: they're not 'all the rest of the arguments' which is what you want.

There are two approaches to solving this problem, described in sections below.

### The first approach: use `apply`

The first and the simplest is to use `apply` whose purpose in life is to deal with this: if you want to call a function with a bunch of arguments you have in a list, as well as perhaps some leading arguments you have individually, you do so with `apply`:

```
> (apply #'func-two 1 2 '(3 4))
4 arguments
param-1: 1
param-2: 2
params:  (3 4)

> (apply #'func-two '(1 2 3 4))
4 arguments
param-1: 1
param-2: 2
params:  (3 4)
```

You can see what `apply` is doing: the first argument to it is the function to call, the *last* argument to it is 'all the rest of the arguments' and any arguments between are some leading arguments.

[The remainder of this answer talks about design, which is necessarily a matter of opinion.]

Using `apply` is a perfectly decent technical answer (there are some issues about arglist length & performance but I think those are secondary here).  However, it is very often the case that having to use `apply` in this way is a symptom of some kind of design problem.  To see why this is consider what your function definitions imply to the human reader.

```
(defun frobnicate (a b &rest things-to-process) ...)
```

What this means is that the `frobnicate` function really has three arguments in its body (calling it binds three variables), where the third argument is some list of things to process.  But at the *user* level I want to call it without having to specify that list explicitly, so I specify this third argument as `&rest` which means the function actually takes two or more arguments from the caller's perspective.

But then consider this code fragment:

```
(apply #'frobnicate this that things-to-process)
```

What does this mean to someone reading it?  Well, it means that you know exactly what function you want to call, `frobnicate`, and you *already have* the three arguments that `frobnicate` actually wants: whatever the leading two are, and then the list of things to process.  But because of the way `frobnicate` is defined you can't just pass them to it: instead you have to spread `things-to-process` into a set of individual arguments with `apply` *and then immediately unspread it back into a (new) list* in the process of calling `frobnicate`.  That smells bad.

In general if you end up having to use `apply` to spread arguments to a function *which you wrote, and whose name you know at the time of writing the code which calls it* then this is often a sign of some kind of impedance-mismatch in the design.

### The second approach: change the design

So the second answer to the problem is to change the design so this impedence-mismatch does not happen.  A way of solving impedance-mismatches like this is to define things in layers:

```
(defun frobnicate (a b &rest things-to-process)
  ;; user convenience function
  (frob a b things-to-process))

(defun frob (a b things-to-process)
  ;; implementation
  ...)
```

And now, within the implementation where you've already got the list of objects to process, you call `frob` rather than `frobnicate`, and you no longer need to use `apply`.

Comment: I need to look closely at this (and experiment), but why do you write "apply is really a solution of last resort". Not that I particularly like the syntax, but at least it makes simple something which I think should not be so difficult to start with. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that the last two paragraphs are debatable.  It really depends on the situation; I don't think that characterizing `apply` as a “last resort” is helpful.

Comment: I've hived off the section on why I think needing `apply` indicates a problem and indicated clearly that it's a design issue & hence a matter of (my) opinion.

Comment: @eMBee: I've added a modified version of your suggested edit, with explicit sections: I hope that's OK.

Comment: it's your answer, so of course it's ok. also now it's even better.

Comment: btw:i also agree that frequent use of apply within your own code is a sign of bad code structure, similar to frequent use of multiple-value-list. both make more sense when you interface with other packages that are out of your scope to change.

Comment: @tfb. Thanks for this tiny lecture. It works and I learned something interesting.

Comment: @Michel I hope I wasn't 'lecturing' you in the bad sense!  Not intended that way & sorry if so!

Comment: Why sorry? I was no bad sense at all, only one way to say thank you. It's always interesting to learn by getting a new perspective, thanks to others.